# Convert an emgu code to GPU

Tags: gpu, emgucv

I am totally new in GPU programing , i have no experience before working with a GPU  , I have some functions , I have to convert those functions so that they run in GPU , The cpu version is running fine , I have used emgucv for image operations . My code is given bellow , please help me .

```
public static Image Highlight(Image image)
    {
      if (image == null)
      {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("image");
      }

      using (Image<Bgr, byte> originalImage = ConvertToEmgu(image))
      using (Image<Bgr, byte> resavedOriginalImage = ConvertToEmgu(ResaveImageWithGivenCompression(image)))
      using (Image<Bgr, byte> errorLevelImage = (originalImage - resavedOriginalImage) * scalingFactor)
      {
        return errorLevelImage.ToBitmap();
      }
    }

    private static Image<Bgr, byte> ConvertToEmgu(Image image)
    {
      using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image))
      {
        return new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap);
      }
    }

    private static Image ResaveImage(Image image)
    {
      EncoderParameters jpegEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
      ImageCodecInfo jpegWithGivenCompressionFormat = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");

      jpegEncoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, compressionQuality);

      using (MemoryStream resavedImageStream = new MemoryStream())
      {
        image.Save(resavedImageStream, jpegWithGivenCompressionFormat, jpegEncoderParameters);

        return Image.FromStream(resavedImageStream);
      }
    }

    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
    {
      ImageCodecInfo[] encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

      return encoders.FirstOrDefault(encoder => encoder.MimeType == mimeType);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is a really poorly researched question. You haven't even said what API/framework you want to work in on the target GPU. Please edit your question to include some more information about what it is you are trying to do and what you don't understand.

Comment: Ok , With the code i have posted , i want to run these functions in GPU , i am working on .NET framework 3.5 and using visualstudio 2008 . What i am not familiar with is what i have to do to add the gpu support to these function.

Comment: You already said that in the question. But you haven't even said what language and API you are planning on writing the *GPU code* in. If you don't even have an idea about that, you are not ready to ask a question about implmentation details on StackOVerflow.

Comment: Sorry , Actually i have mentioned that i have used emgucv for image operations so i am using c# and i want to do those image operations in GPU . In this program there is not much complicated image operations are there , just some image differences are taken . I want to add gpu support for that part .

Answer (score 4):

- First you need a Graphics card that supports CUDA at least 2.0.
- Then you have to install the CUDA drivers from NVidia. Search for
  CUDA toolkit.
- Then you need to include the CUDA dlls in your project (Just like you
  did with the Opencv dlls)
- Then you need to use the CV.GPU namespace
- Then you replace all your functions with the appropriate GPU version.
  In your code I do not see any OpenCV functions so there is nothing to
  replace.  (But I could be missing some)

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the following websites to answer your question

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCV_GPU
http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html
http://blog.cuvilib.com/2011/03/22/how-to-build-opencv-2-2-with-gpu-cuda-on-windows-7/